# Update website from daily email

Tags: php, html-email

Bear with me, this sounds like a random thing to want to do but here goes...

I receive a daily email (HTML format) from one of my suppliers that is always in the same layout / format. Is there any way that I can 'tap' into this email and essentially loop through each row, adding records to a DB automatically.

I'm thinking that the only way to do this would be to manually copy out the HTML and run it through a script that does this but wanted to check the talent on here first. Maybe an amazing piece of software I never knew existed... Want to eliminate any type of manual work if possible.

Any suggestions welcome.

Edit: Maybe my question is more along the lines of "How do I run a script against an email from within my mail client, automatically?"

Comment: if the question is about a mail client VS scripting in it, perhaps you may want to retag the question?

Comment: I'm not sure myself really...

Comment: It sounds *plausible* but probably more effort than you think it is. I would suggest checking if the supplier can email you a CSV (or attach one) which would make it a *hell* of a lot easier. If you uses Outlook, you can then easily extract the CSV attachment through VBA, or you could also use imap_open to get into your email account directly.

Comment: Does your mail client allow you to set rules? If so maybe you could make it copy all emails received from <your client> into a folder. Once you have the email as a file with a known format it ought to be straightforward to read a row at a time and then extract the details to create an INSERT statement for your database.

Comment: I agree - what I need is very niche and overkill and yes I am lazy, isn't it in our nature as developers to want to create an app that does our work for us :-)

Comment: Sorry, I will not follow [your invitation to undress](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1270/300).

Comment: You know, I actually typed bear before and changed it!

Comment: Maybe try this? https://sitemailcms.com/ Using our service, you can send emails to quickly and easily update your website instantly. Whatever you put in your emails will appear on your website exactly the way you type it, including special formatting, pictures and other attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write script that would fetch mail from your mailbox (best, receive them to separate mailboxes) using i.e. POP3 or IMAP mail protocol. Parse it as you like (maybe try `mailparse` extension for this). Process how you like. Then set cron to launch your script with certain frequency (like once a day).

Comment: Pretty obvious solution, I didn't even think of this